# How to enable CSS Critical Path in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, css, admin-panel, optimization

How to enable CSS Critical Path in Magento 2.3?

**Ref:** https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-critical-path.html

When I try to enable it, I'm getting the below error.

```
The "dev/css/use_css_critical_path" path doesn't exist. Verify and try again.
```

Comment: For the compilation of the critical CSS, you can use this gulp implementation.
https://github.com/bobmotor/magento-2-gulp

Comment: Check this one : https://bit.ly/3gveJRY

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will probably be added in v2.3.3. This is the MR: https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/fb9a02ae025d102744857f981b702c0fe32c23d2

Comment: It's weird how the documentation for this is already live and for 2.2 as well despite the files not being in 2.2 or 2.3 yet.

Comment: This confused me as well and I was referred to the MR after asking around on the M2 Community Engineers Slack channel.

Answer (score 2):

You can enable it via admin panel **Stores > Settings > Configuration > ADVANCED > Developer** or via terminal.

[image: Magento 2.4 critical css]

```
bin/magento config:set dev/css/use_css_critical_path 1
```

## How to use it

You can create a critical.css in your custom theme as the example below.

```
app/design/frontend/<your_vendor_name>/<your_theme_name>/web/css/critical.css
```

Reference: [Magento 2.4 DevDocs - CSS critical path](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css-critical-path.html)

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to disable it - return back to option "No".
Is there CLI command or something else?